# Getting Error Like RequestsLimitError: You just made too many request to instagram API in node js?

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

I am work with isntagram api in node js. i have one array and in the array store above 20k up instagram id. and  then i am do foreach on that array and one by one take instagram id and go for the take bio but that time i am **getting error like** this **RequestsLimitError: You just made too many request to instagram API**. i am try every 5 call after set time out also but still i am getting same error so how can resolved this error any one know how can fix it then please let me know.

Here this is my code =>

```
var InstaId = ["12345687",20k more id store here in the array]

        var changesessionFlage = 0;
        async.each(InstaId, function (id, callback) {
            async.parallel([
                function (cb) {
                    if (id) {                                                
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            Client.Account.getById(sess, id).then(function (bio) {                                    
                                console.log("changesessionFlage" + changesessionFlage);                                    
                                changesessionFlage++                                    
                                //console.log("bio : ", bio._params);   // here  i am getting bio one by one user                                

                                if (changesessionFlage == 6) {
                                    changesessionFlage = 0;
                                }                                   

                                cb(null, bio._params);

                            })
                           .catch(function (err) {
                               console.log("get boi: ", err)
                               cb(null, bio._params);
                           })
                          }, (changesessionFlage == 5) ? 10000 : 0)                            
                    }
                }
            ], function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                Result = results
                callback();
            });
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            else {
                console.log("Result=>", Result)
                if (Result) {                      
                    console.log("Result[0]=>", Result[0])
                    var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(Result[0]);
                    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "People");
                    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
                    res.end(wbout, 'binary');
                }
            }                
        });
```

any one know how can fix this issue then please help me.

Comment: There are some limits https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: @Molda it's not possible using setimeout and fix that issue it's possible?

Comment: The limit is 500 or 5000 (sandbox or live app) requests per hour, so adjust your timeout to make sure you don't exceed the limit.

Comment: @Molda i have set time out but i have run my req in the console so it's same time run not stop for the time out so it's code it's correct or my mistake in that code? actully i have used asyn.parralel so

Answer (score 0):

Your setTimeout is use incorrectly, all API calls are made at once after 10000 delay.

Since this is a one time job, just split the 20K usernames to 4K batches and execute them every hour. This way you will be under the 5k/hr API limit